# MS Access automatically create copy upon opening access

Tags: windows, ms-access

I have the following problem:

We have an MS Access file on a remote server which is accessed by 3 people. Each day a backup should be made by copying the file and renaming it.
(I have no access to the server, so can't put a script on there!)

Is there a possibility to start the backup process once the first person opens the file and do a backup unless it already exists?

Or do you have any other suggestions that are easy to implement?

I would be really grateful for any help here. Not really a Windows person.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use VBA and the FileSystemObject:

```
Function BackUp()
Dim fs As Object 'FileSystemObject
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & Format(DATE, "yyyymmdd.bak")
If Not fs.FileExists(FileName) Then
    fs.copyfile CurrentProject.FullName, FileName, False
End If
End Function
```

The function can be run by creating an autoexec macro - a macro called autoexec will run when the database is opened.

However, there seems to be some problems in that you have not specified where the back-end or front-end of your application reside. Also, it would be by far the best thing that such a copy is run when no users are accessing the back-end.

Comment: hi. I'm not really sure if this info is correct, but I think that there is no distinction between back-end and front-end. It's not a very well programmed application (I didn't do it, I just have to work with it since a bit)